# momentJS: date(0) returning last day of last month

Tags: momentjs

I want to get the last day of present month.
But when I use date(0), it is returning last day of previous month.
Why ? Is it relative to present day??

```
var time=moment().tz("America/New_York");
console.log(new Date(time));
console.log(moment().tz("America/New_York").date(0));
```

**Output:**

> Wed Nov 02 2016 15:01:43 GMT+0530 (IST) 
>   Mon Oct 31 2016 15:01:43
>   GMT+0530 (IST)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`endOf()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/) function to get the end of the month, as shown in the following example:

```js
var time = moment.tz("America/New_York");
var endOfMonth = time.endOf('month');
console.log(endOfMonth.format());
console.log(endOfMonth.date());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.7/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

var startDate = moment().subtract('months',1).endOf('month')